# How to provide READ, WRITE grant to public SYNONYM based on Directroy

Tags: oracle

I created a directory, then I created one public synonym for that directory and tried to grant READ/WRITE on the synonym, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SYNONYM.html#GUID-A806C82F-1171-478E-A910-F9C6C42739B2), you cannot create a synonym for a directory. Thing is when you create the synonym, the database will not complain, as it will check the synonym when you try to use it. That's why you get an error when you execute your grant.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.